# C# find function problem (Can't highlight)

Tags: c#, winforms, find, richtextbox

I would like to ask why does my codes not work?

Currently, I am able to find the word the user input but it cannot highlight the word in the richTextBoxConversation.

How should I go about doing it?

Following are my codes:

```
    private void buttonTextFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string s1 = richTextBoxConversation.Text.ToLower();
        string s2 = textBoxTextFilter.Text.ToLower();

        if (s1.Contains(s2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Word found!");
            richTextBoxConversation.Find(s2);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Word not found!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you need to do something with the value returned from RichTextBox.Find()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select text in RichTextBox but you need to always remember that text will be in selected mode if that richtextbox has focus, so your code must be

```
// RichTextBox.Select(startPos,length)

int startPos = richTextBoxConversation.Find(s2); 

int length = s2.Length;

if (startPos > -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Word found!");
    // Now set focus on richTextBox
    richTextBoxConversation.Focus();
    richTextBoxConversation.Select(startPos , length );
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Word not found!");
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply. Your codes work if I place them in the same form. If I place them in another form, it cannot work.

Comment: Anyway, do you know how to create a find next function? If there are more than 1 of the same word, I would like to like to have a find next function so that I can see the rest of that word being highlighted from the richtextbox.

Answer (score 6):

You are using the [`Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfcsf75k.aspx) method - this simply tells you *where* in the textbox the word exists, it does not select it.

You can use the return value from `Find` with [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx) in order to "highlight" the word:

```
if (s1.Contains(s2))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Word found!");
  int wordPosition = richTextBoxConversation.Find(s2); // Get position
  richTextBoxConversation.Select(wordPosition, s2.Length);
}
```

Or, even better (avoids searching `s1` twice for the word):

```
int wordPosition = richTextBoxConversation.Find(s2); // Get position
if (wordPosition > -1)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Word found!");
  richTextBoxConversation.Select(wordPosition, s2.Length);
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Word not found!");
}
```

Comment: I don't know why but it still doesn't highlight the word in the richtextbox. Anyway, can you explain to me why is it wordposition > -1? Why -1 and not any other numbers?

Comment: @athgap - if you read the documentation on find (I linked it), it will tell you that the return value of `Find` is `-1` if **not found**.